# Using gsub to replace last occurence of string in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub, string-substitution

I have the following character vector than I need to modify with `gsub`.

```
strings <- c("x", "pm2.5.median", "rmin.10000m", "rmin.2500m", "rmax.5000m")
```

Desired output of filtered `strings`:

```
"x", "pm2.5.median", "rmin", "rmin", "rmax"
```

My current attempt works for everything except the `pm2.5.median` string which has dots that need to be preserved. I'm really just trying to remove the buffer size that is appended to the end of each variable, e.g. `1000m`, `2500m`, `5000m`, `7500m`, and `10000m`.

```
gsub("\\..*m$", "", strings)
"x", "pm2", "rmin", "rmin", "rmax"
```

Comment: Please see the answers below and consider accepting the one that worked best for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Match a dot, any number of digits, `m` and the end of string and replace that with the empty string.  Note that we prefer `sub` to `gsub` here because we are only interested in one replacement per string.

```
sub("\\.\\d+m$", "", strings)
## [1] "x"            "pm2.5.median" "rmin"         "rmin"         "rmax"
```

Comment: This is working for me too. Thanks! Why is there a preference for `sub` over `gsub`?

Comment: I have added the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The `.*` pattern matches any 0 or more chars, as many as possible. The `\..*m$` pattern matches the first (leftmost) `.` in the string and then grab all the text after it if it ends with `m`.

You need

```
> sub("\\.[^.]*m$", "", strings)
[1] "x"            "pm2.5.median" "rmin"         "rmin"         "rmax"
```

Here, `\.[^.]*m$` matches `.`, then 0 or more chars other than a dot and then `m` at the end of the string.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/ihzL0I/1).

**Details**

- `\.` - a dot (must be escaped since it is a special regex char otherwise)
- `[^.]*` - a negated character class matching any char but `.` 0 or more times
- `m`  - an `m` char
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Wiktor can you tell why you used this pattern `[^.]*` instead of `\\d+` as in G.Grothendieck's answer? I.e. what is the advantage here? (I am a regex beginner still)

Comment: @markus Judging by the current sample input data the strings are period-separated strings. The `.` that should be matched is the last dot in the string. So, the point is to match the dot that has no dots up to the end of the string, and `[^.]*` fits this need. It is preferable if there may be other chars that just digits between the last `.` and final `m`.